# How to keep player size constant when video changes in videojs?

Tags: html5-video, video.js, window-resize, autoresize

Every time a video changes, the player resizes(according to video dimensions) I dont want that.

I want the player to be able to resize when browser size changes but not when the video changes. How can I achieve this?

I am also using videojs-playlist-ui so I want that the height of the player to be the same size as the playlist.

In other words, for the same window size, I should have the same player size independent of the video. (Video ratio should be preserved)

Answer (score 0):

Add a style tag to the parent div.

`<div id="videodiv" style="width:500px">`

Comment: I want that the size changes on windows size change. So setting a width is not acceptable